# pythonのCLIで、リファレンスをHTMLで出力する方法

Tags: python

## やりたいこと

Pythonの[argparse](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/howto/argparse.html)モジュールを使って、CLIを作っています。
CLIの使い方は、`--help`引数を指定すればターミナルで確認できますが、できればwebでも確認できるようにしたいです。

イメージとしては、awscliのように、ヘルプコマンドとwebのリファレンスの内容を一致させたいです。

#### awscliのヘルプコマンド

```
$ aws s3 list help

LS()                                                                      LS()



NAME
       ls -

DESCRIPTION
       List  S3  objects and common prefixes under a prefix or all S3 buckets.
       Note that the --output and --no-paginate arguments are ignored for this
       command.

       See 'aws help' for descriptions of global parameters.

SYNOPSIS
            ls
          <S3Uri> or NONE
          [--recursive]
          [--page-size <value>]
          [--human-readable]
          [--summarize]
          [--request-payer <value>]

OPTIONS
       paths (string)

       --recursive  (boolean)  Command  is  performed  on all files or objects
       under the specified directory or prefix.
```

#### awscliのwebのリファレンス

[image: awscli s3 ls]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html

## 質問

CLIのリファレンスを、HTMLとして出力するのによいツールやパターンがあれば教えてください。
単純な方法だと、「`argparse`にヘルプメッセージを渡し、HTML(実際はsphinxを使う予定)にもヘルプメッセージを書く」という方法もありますが、これだと二重管理になってしまいます。

awscliのソースを見て、どのような仕組みになっているか探してみましたが、よく分かりませんでした。
"Examples"の内容は、reStructuredTextで書かれたファイルを読み込んでいるらしいことは分かりました。

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/274ee71cb3180e557a54f9445cca2b6a7a998d24/awscli/examples/s3/ls.rst

#### 環境

- Python3.8
- awscli 1.18.147

Answer (score 0):

`htmlgen` というpythonスクリプトが `awscli.clidriver` 経由で `ProviderHelpCommand` を呼び出し、その内容から生成しているようです。

- `htmlgen`
  https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/master/doc/source/htmlgen
- `ProviderHelpCommand`
  https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/master/awscli/help.py#L276